Conformal Map of a Simply Connected Region to a Disk Centered at the Origin
This is a question from an old complex analysis qualifying exam.
Suppose that $f$ maps a simply connected region $G$ one-to-one and conformally onto a circular disk $D_r$ with center $0,$ radius $r$, such that $f(a) = 0$ and $|f'(a)| = 1$ for some point $a \in G.$
Prove that the radius $r = r(G,a)$ of $D_r$ is uniquely determined by $G$ and $a.$
The solution states:
Suppose $g(z)$ is another conformal map of $G$ onto a circular disk $D_{r_1}$ with center $0$ and radius $r_1$, such that $g(a)  = 0$ and $|g'(a)| = 1$, then $f \circ g^{-1}$ is a conformal map of $D_{r_1}$ onto $D_{r}$ with $f \circ g^{-1}(0) = 0$ and $|(f \circ g^{-1})'(0)|= \left|\frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)} \right|=1.$ Apply Schwarz lemma to $f \circ g^{-1}$ and we have $|(f \circ g^{-1})'(0)| \leq \frac{r}{r_1}$, hence $r_1 \leq r$. For the same reason, apply Schwarz lemma to $(f \circ g^{-1})^{-1}$ and we have $r \leq r_1$, which implies $r_1 = r$. In other words, $r$ is uniquely determined by $G$ and $a$.
My questions are the following: How can we apply Schwarz lemma to the maps $f \circ g^{-1}$ and $(f \circ g^{-1})^{-1}$, if the Schwarz lemma requires the map to be from the unit disk to itself (we have no restriction placed on $r$ and $r_1$ making them equal to 1)? If we can indeed, somehow, apply the Schwarz lemma, why can we deduce that $|(f \circ g^{-1})'(0)| \leq \frac{r}{r_1}$ and a similar inequality for the other map?

Let's say we are looking at $h := f \circ g^{-1}$.
Define $$u : z \in D_1 \,\longmapsto\, \frac{1}{r} h(r_1 z) \in D_1$$
By the Schwarz lemma, $|u'(0)| \leq 1$, yet:
$$u'(z) = \frac{r_1}{r}h'(r_1z)$$
thus:
$$u'(0) = \frac{r_1}{r}h'(0) = \frac{r_1}{r}$$
This yields $r_1 \leq r$ like promised, and the exact same process can be done with $h^{-1}$ to get the other inequality.
